# Can XSLT be used to form a plain txt file, not just html?

Tags: xslt

Lately I have become a huge fan of XSL, XPath and XML, but I've only used it to format outputted html documents, with a head and body sections.

I was wondering if its possible to use good of XSLT to format other types of documents, like plain txt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes of course - just use

```
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
```

instead of

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
```

Marc

UPDATE: whitespace and formatting text exactly as needed are always a bit tricky in XSLT. Check out some of those references:

- [XML.com: controlling whitespace](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/11/07/whitespace.html)
- [XSL Primer](http://www.whitefrost.com/documents/html/technical/xsl/xslPrimer.html#part5) (part 5 has a note about whitespace)

Comment: Thanks Marc, will line breaks occur naturally, same as in the template?

Comment: If you use direct element constructors, whitespace within will be collapsed by the usual rules. `<xsl:text>` is space-preserving, and lets you control output at character precision, however.